# Logout in Spring Boot with Vaadin not possible. Why?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, vaadin

I create a simple spring boot application. When I add the vaadin dependency in the pom.xml. The logout is not possible. The User is still login and not need to type in the password.

I get the same result for Vaadin 10 and Vaadin 12. The spring version is 2.1.2.RELEASE

```
@RestController
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApplication {  
    @RequestMapping("/")
    String home() {return "Hello World!";}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
    }
}    

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.httpBasic().and().
        .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated();
    http.httpBasic().and().logout()
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/")
    .invalidateHttpSession(true).deleteCookies("JSESSIONID");
    }
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
         BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
         auth.inMemoryAuthentication().passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder()).withUser("thomas")
            .password(encoder.encode("xxx")).roles("USER");
      }
}

Dependeny:
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
 <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I expect follow results

I call localhost:xxx/ => the browser ask the username/password

I call localhost:xxx/logout => the browser ask the username/password again

After I add the vaadin dependeny into the pom

I get follow results

I call localhost:xxx/ => the browser ask the username/password

I call localhost:xxx/logout => the browser do not ask the password!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are using basic authentication, which doesn't really support logout. In every request the browser sends the username/password, so the user is logged back in right after logout.

One way to solve this would be to change authentication to form and provide a page with a form where the user can submit the login credentials.

```java
http.formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
```

in `/login` you should provide a html page with a `<form>` tag that posts the login credentials, like for instance:

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
   <h1>Login</h1>
   <form name='f' action="login" method='POST'>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <td>User:</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='username' value=''></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Password:</td>
            <td><input type='password' name='password' /></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td><input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" /></td>
         </tr>
      </table>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

(Taken from https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-login)